# How to load class file of the ui file loaded using QuiLoader in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT and am facing trouble using the QUiLoader Class. What I am trying to achieve is to load another ui file on a button click in the same window, which is working fine. But the new ui file loaded has a button in it which when clicked is supposed to execute a certain code (say print "hi") which is not happening somehow. The button appears but does nothing. Somehow the class file of the newly loaded dashboard.ui file is  not being included.

Here is my code which loads the new ui file

```
QUiLoader loader;
QFile file(":/dashboard.ui");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QWidget *myWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
qDebug() << loader.pluginPaths();
file.close();
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(myWidget);
```

Is there a way through which I can include the class file of dashboard.ui so that the button works perfectly again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect the signals, that code (apparently) does not do it automatically. There are two ways to go about it. Note: untested code, there may be errors.

### Automatic connects by slot name

If you have methods with right name in your parent class, you can use [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName):

```
...
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(myWidget); // first myWidget must have parent set
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this); // connect matching signals from children
...
```

Assuming the button name is, for example "myLoadedButton", and you want the `clicked()` signal, then with above code you must have `on_myLoadedButton_clicked()` slot in the class of `this` object.

Warning: The docs don't say and I didn't check the source, so this *might* do duplicate connections if called multiple times. So watch out for this, and if this hits you, then you have to use the approach below:

### Manual connects

If you have different slot names or want to connect to other than parent, you can also do connections yourself, by using [`QObject::findChild`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

```
...
QPushButton *button = myWidget->findChild<QPushButton *>("myLoadedButton");
if (button) {
   QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(loadedButtonPress()));
} 
// else widget not found, print error?
```